# How to convert a File to a Blob in Javascript without FileReader?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to convert a File into a Blob without using FileReader. I can't use FileReader because the latest version of Typescript (which I must use) doesn't accept a File as the parameter to `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`.

Using FileReader I can do it as follows:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(e) {
  new Blob([ this.result ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
};

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

How can I achieve the same result without FileReader?

Comment: If I remember right, `File` is a subclass of `Blob`, so you shouldn't even need to use `FileReader`, it just already is a `Blob`. You could always cast to an `any` though if Typescript has issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always augment the declaration in lib.d.ts with an overload accepting a `File`.

For example, create a file named `globals.d.ts` with the following content

```
interface FileReader {
    readAsArrayBuffer(file: File): void;
}
```

That said, if the declaration was changed, I would be wary of this behavior as some environments likely do not support it.